# MFMailComposeViewController disables scrolling

Tags: ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Im using `MFMailComposeViewController`. I have a `UIScrollView` which contains a few labels, a `UIWebview` and a `UIImageview`. When I tap the mail button which eventually calls the `MFMailComposeViewController` method, the scrollview doesn't scroll anymore.

Here is the code I am using for `MFMailComposeViewController`:

```
- (void)message
{    
MFMailComposeViewController *mailcontroller =
[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
[mailcontroller setMailComposeDelegate:self];
[mailcontroller setSubject:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",news_Title]];
[mailcontroller setMessageBody:bodyMail isHTML:YES];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

[self presentViewController:mailcontroller animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: The MFMailComposeViewController presents its own View on top of the viewcontroller's view that presents it. The other view is not supposed to take user actions in that case and that's why your scrollview is not scrolling.

Comment: @Puneet Ok i understand the problem. Isn't [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; supposed to solve that problem?

Comment: You should make your question more specific. Are you saying that your normal view stops scrolling after you dismiss the mail controller view?

Comment: @BillBurgess What part of my question is not clear?
"I have a UIScrollView which contains a few labels, a UIWebview and a UIImageview"
This means i have only one single view. And yes the very same stops scrolling.

Comment: Can you please show your `-viewWillAppear`, `-viewDidAppear`, `-viewWillDisappear`, `-viewDidDisappear` methods?